# Load module from the boot menu

Tags: boot, kernel-modules, sles

Is there a way to insert/load a module at the boot menu in Suse?  I'm referring to the menu in the screenshot below (this isn't from my machine, just a similar screenshot I took from the web).

I know you add modules to boot via INITRD_MODULES in /etc/sysconfig/kernel, but I'm unable to get into my root partition, even in rescue mode.  I did an in-place upgrade to SLES 11 SP2 and this new service pack seems to have an issue with booting my iSCSI HBA.

The proper qla4xxx driver loads fine, but no disks are found.  I've been through hours of troubleshooting and found that two drivers need to be loaded in SP2 that I previously never needed:  iscsi_boot_sysfs and libiscsi.  I want to see if I can specify these two at the main menu and force them to load during boot.  Thanks.

[image: SLES Boot menu]

Comment: Does this setup load an initrd or initramfs? If it does, the initramfs has access to the kernel command line and could interpret some argument as a request to load a module (inside the initramfs). I don't know whether that is implemented on SuSE.

Comment: It loads initrd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to load any module at boot. The kernel first needs to be loaded ... which will not happen if I understand correctly your problem. All you can do from a boot menu is sent parameters to the kernel, but that's all. If you can't load the kernel itself you do not really have any option.

However, maybe you could boot into a live session, load the required modules after you boot into live session with `modprobe`, than mount your disk, chroot into it an install the missing modules...

Still these are just speculations because I have no way to test your setup.

Comment: I'm able to mount root from the rescue system and chroot to it, but after adding the missing modules, I'm unable to run mkinitrd.  It says root device /dev/sd.. not found.  I may download and try a live CD (something other than the SLES rescue mode) and see if I have better luck.